# Bitbucket server API: is it possible to checkout/pull/merge via API?

Tags: synchronization, branching-and-merging, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-server

I'm writing some automatic scripts using Bitbucket Server API.
I have a lot of actions here, with pull request creation, etc.

For some reason I need to synchronize some branch with remote and merge with other branches(git merge).

Is it possible to do something like:

```
git checkout my_branch
git pull
git merge another_branch
```

I can do this staff via direct shell calls, but it requires branch cloning, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: [GitPython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/) library for example does abstract the git commands

Comment: @DanIonescu, don't I need to clone my repository before using of this library?

Comment: yes but the clonning can also be made from the python library and if you're worried about disk space you can delete it afterwards

Comment: @DanIonescu, it's not so easy, because my repository is huge enough and it may be too long...

Comment: Try bitbucket [API](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/4.14.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45183781754144) they have a POST request in their REST API for merge operations

Comment: @DanIonescu, where? I can see just for merging pull requestsm but I'm not sure if it's the same...

Comment: You're right you it's not the same thing, you have to create a pull request first and then merge it..

Comment: @DanIonescu, I'm interesting first, in auto-merging(fast-forwarding), and then create pull request(if it's needed)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new [edit API](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/4.13.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45295355532832) (since 4.13) if you just want to edit a single file. 
Git itself *is* the API we'd recommend for manipulating Git repos otherwise.

Regarding repo sizes, you can do a shallow clone with modern versions of Git to pull down less data, and still push back. Depending on your scenario, you might also be able to maintain a local copy over time instead of cloning each time.